Understanding the ADC full scale input compared to a the reference voltage level of ADC
I have read this post here: Negative Voltage Reference for Bipolar ADC
It touches on some of the points, and I am confused about the maximum input range of the ADC compared to the reference inputs.
I want to measure +/- 2V, and I have +/- 2.5V rails for the ADC. I use -2.5V as my REFN, and I use a 4.096V reference between REFN to REFP, such the voltage on REFN is -2.5V and the voltage on REFP is (-2.5+4.06) 1.596V.
If my input voltage is 2V, can the ADC measure this as its above its REFP input voltage? Does the ADC care about this? Or if I understand correctly, all the ADC cares about is the difference between REFP to REFN and this determines the maximum differential range of the ADC.
https://www.ti.com/product/ADS1258
Thanks.


The circuit you have added is incorrect compared to what you state in your words. Have you read the data sheet? If so, please link it inside your post.

@Andyaka Hi Andy, updated

The full-scale input voltage is the reference voltage. Refer to page 3 of the ADS1258 datasheet:

The full-scale input voltage is  ~VREF, this is the range of voltages over which the ADC can differentiate. Then you have the absolute input voltage, which is the upper and lower bounds of the input voltage that you absolutely should not cross because it may damage the chip.
So if you have ±2.5 V rails, but only -2.5/+1.596 V VREFn/p, then you can read input voltages in the range -2.5 to 1.596 V and get accurate measurements.
You can have input voltages of 1.596 to 2.5 V, but your ADC will read any of those voltages as 1.596 V
I'm not sure I formatted this answer in a very readable way so let me break it down for different input voltages:

V < -2.5 V: inadvisable, could damage the chip
V= -2.5 V to 1.596 V: Will operate as intended
V = 1.596 V to 2.5 V: safe, but ADC will read as +1.596V
V > 2.5 V: inadvisable, could damage the chip


It's the square-bracket stuff that looks really clunky and doesn't let the numbers show through, but it looks like that's your favourite bit :-) 'to' would be clearer, will do a demo edit to show if that's OK then I'll leave you to your preferences. A space between quantity and units is pretty standard.

@TonyM didn't mean to take out the unit spaces there. "[ ... ]" is standard notation for ranges so I read it fine, but "to" works for me if it works for everyone else!

Have upvoted, good answer. So long as it expresses what you want to say and looks clear to us, we're all OK :-) (Incidentally, it's '..' for ranges, while '...' is an ellipsis for grammar.)

@TonyM I hadn't seen that before but I did catch on to the difference, yes. I was using "..." as a signifier for omitted material inside a quotation.

@InBedded16 I think your answer is incorrect. The ADC can measure any differential voltage in the range of ±1.067 Vref = ±4.37 V as long as both input signals stay within AVdd to AVss. The author may use the full input range of ±2 V that he desires.

@Simon what makes you think that Vref = ±4.095 V? In the question it is clearly stated that Vrefp = 1.596 V and Vrefn = -2.5 V. Vref has a range of 4.096 V, but a) that would mean Vref=±2.048 V and b) it is not centered around 0 V so that would not be correct either.

@Simon you know what I read the datasheet again and I can see your side. I've never used an ADC that had a Vrefp/n and didn't use them to set the actual voltage bounds, but it seems like this one might do just that. Its still ambiguous to me though, it kind of alludes to that without ever definitively saying it.

Your understanding is absolutely correct.
Since Vrefp would exceed AVdd if you referenced it to GND, you have to reference it to AVSS = -2.5 V instead. The ADC will receive a reference voltage of 4.096 V nevertheless and use ±1.067 Vref as its reference voltage.
Your input signal of ±2 V is always within the allowable differential input range of ±1.067 Vref = 4.37 V and the input voltage always stays within AVdd and AVss.
In my opinion, your configuration will function as intended.
